# What's the time complexity of this piece of code?

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I'm studying for exam and I came across this piece of code and I need to find best and worst case.

```
  A(n):
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i*=2) {
     for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (i == j) return; // does nothing
        for (int k = n; k > 0; k--)
           if (f(n)) 
              return g(n);
     }
  }
```

whereas functions worst and best cases are:

> `f(n) O(n) Ω(log^7(n))`

> `g(n)  O(n^2 * log^6(n)) Ω(n^2 * log^6(n))`

**Worst case:**
Complexity of the first loop is `log(n)`, and the second loop depends on first but I would say that it's complexity is `n`. Third for loop is `n`. `f(n)` is checked in O(n) and in worst case `g(n)` will be executed in last iteration and it's complexity is O(n^2 * log^6(n)). So I would say that worst case is `log(n) * n * n * n + n^2 * log^6(n)`, so it's **`O(n^3 * log(n))`**.

Other logic would be, that as second loop depends on the first one, the iterations will go `1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16...` which is geometric series and it's value is `2^log(n)` which is `n`.  Everything under first loop would stay same, so in this case Big-O would be **`O(n^3)`**

**Best case:** I found that the best case would be `(n^2 * log^6(n))` as it would go straight to `return` statement without iterating at all.

Basically, the main question is how does `log(n)` times executed loop affects nested `n` times executed loop which depends on it.
Which logic is right for worst case, and is the best case ok?

Comment: Your reasoning about the geometric series is correct.

Comment: @SupportUkraine Yeah, it's there just to confuse.

Comment: You use the terms "best case" and "worst case", but it's not clear what those terms mean in context -- what is a "case" here? Usually "best case" and "worst case" refer to problems where the size of the input (n) is not the only thing that affects the runtime -- for example, sorting a list of length n may have a "best case" of linear if the list is nearly already sorted.

Comment: I expect the question is intended to be to calculate upper and lower complexity bounds given only the information provided in the question. That's Omega(n^2 log^6 n) and O(n^3). You have to note that g(n) will either be executed in the first loop iteration (and the function will terminate), or never, because f does not depend on i, j or k.

Comment: @PaulHankin What you say is true if `f` and `g` are pure functions. But I suppose they` could contain some randomness in which case best-case and worst-case analysis makes sense, and g(n) could then be executed in any iteration.